# Using boost::fast_pool_allocator in place of std::allocator

Tags: boost, c++11, allocator

I'm trying to use `boost::fast_pool_allocator` in place of the standard allocator and it won't work (ironically with another boost library) because `fast_pool_allocator` has more than one template parameter even though it claims to be compatible with `std::allocator` and everything except the first has a default value.

I am trying to pass it as a class template that expects a single template parameter. The specific error:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list for "template<class Point, template<class, class> class Container, template<class> class Allocator> class boost::geometry::model::multi_point"

error: expected a template of type "template<class> class Allocator", got "template<class T, class UserAllocator, class Mutex, unsigned int NextSize, unsigned int MaxSize> class boost::fast_pool_allocator"
```

Is there a way to make this actually work?

Comment: Sounds like Boost.Geometry is broken. I'd file a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following template instead of `boost::fast_pool_allocator`

```
template <class T>
using fast_pool_allocator_t = boost::fast_pool_allocator<T>;
```

This will also work if you are not using C++11.

```
template <class T>
struct fast_pool_allocator_t : boost::fast_pool_allocator<T>
{ };
```